# Firebase onChildChanged is fired multiple times?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a quantity picker in each item of my recyclerview. While scrolling the quantity values are changed due to Recycling. So I'm trying to update the Map with the latest value & notifyItemChanged with the position whenever a child is removed or changed.

I'm using ChildEventListener to listen changes in the child. But when a single change happens onChildChanged keeps printing util onDestroy is called.

How can I Solve this Issue ? Please Guide me...

```
private void cartListener(int pos) {

        cartRef = mCustDB.child(Email).child("mycart");
        cartRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Timber.d("onChildChanged > " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
01-31 16:34:58.759 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:34:58.782 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:34:59.399 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:34:59.409 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:35:00.055 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:35:01.959 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:35:01.970 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
01-31 16:35:02.599 27963-27963/? D/BrowsePresenter: onChildChanged > c02p02
```

**NOTE**

I'm changing the data only once. But for Each change the method is fired non-stop until I remove the listener!

**UPDATE**

The problem is with the `addToCart` method because if I update the value directly in firebase. The listener is fired only twice.

If I update the value using the below method. It is getting fired multiple times until i remove the Listener.

```
public void addToCart(Product item, int quantity, int position) {
    cartRef = mCustDB.child(Email).child("mycart");

    cartRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String prodID = null;
            List<String> mKey = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                prodID = postSnapshot.getKey();
                mKey.add(prodID);
            }
            if (!mKey.contains(item.productID())) {
                Cart mycart = new Cart(item.productID(), 1);
                cartRef.updateChildren(mycart.toMap());
                Timber.d("updateChildren >> ");
            } else {
                if (quantity == 0) {
                    Timber.d("Remove >> " + item.productID());
                    cartRef.child(item.productID()).removeValue();
                } else {
                    Timber.d("INCREASE >> " + item.productID() + quantity);
                    cartRef.child(item.productID()).setValue(quantity);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

CART

```
public class Cart {

    public String productID;
    public int quantity = 0;

    public Cart() {
    }

    public Cart(String productID, int quantity) {
        this.productID = productID;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Cart(String productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put(productID , quantity);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya its true,Whenever there is na change in database of firebase the method onChildChanged() method called.

Comment: @RishabhMahatha I'm changing the data only once. But the method is triggered many times

Comment: How are you calling the `cartListener()` method and how are you changing the data? I don't think the code posted so far is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Please see the update!

Comment: If `onChildChanged()` gets called multiple times, it is very likely that you changed the/a child multiple times. Please share the [minimal *complete* code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If this requires your `Cart` class, share that. But likely you can also reproduce it without the `Cart` class and just a simple map (and if you can't, you know that the problem is in your `Cart` class :-)).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem arises when i update the value using the `addToCart` method. If I update the value in the Firebase directly. It works as expected!

Comment: OK, so that makes it even more likely that it's a problem in the client-side code that changes the value. Unfortunately I have no experience with RxFirebaseDatabase, so can't help there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This looks like a case of causing a loop by adding a listener to a node, then updating that same node within the listener.

In this case it's `cartRef` in the `addToCart()` method. A `ValueEventListener` is added to `cartRef`, the code in `onDataChange` then updates data under `cartRef`, so the listener is continuously triggering itself.

It seems your listener is to check the state of your cart before deciding how to proceed; perhaps the simplest way to avoid the loop is to add a Single Value Event listener instead so you can still check, but avoid a loop.

```
cartRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
// same listener as before
....
```

Comment: Twice every time? That would seem unusual, can't see from the question what might cause that, but my first thought would be that perhaps the same listener is added multiple times (ie. cartListener() method being called more than once)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in each call to addToCard() you add a new listener, so you must remove the previous listener, like this:

```
public void addToCart(Product item, int quantity, int position) {
    // Add a new propery for the listener
    if (cartRef != null && valueEventListener != null) {
        cartRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }

    cartRef = mCustDB.child(Email).child("mycart");
    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String prodID = null;
            List<String> mKey = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                prodID = postSnapshot.getKey();
                mKey.add(prodID);
            }
            if (!mKey.contains(item.productID())) {
                Cart mycart = new Cart(item.productID(), 1);
                cartRef.updateChildren(mycart.toMap());
                Timber.d("updateChildren >> ");
            } else {
                if (quantity == 0) {
                    Timber.d("Remove >> " + item.productID());
                    cartRef.child(item.productID()).removeValue();
                } else {
                    Timber.d("INCREASE >> " + item.productID() + quantity);
                    cartRef.child(item.productID()).setValue(quantity);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    cartRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check where you are setting you `eventListner` if you are using it somewhere where it is called again and again than it will call the `it functions` the number of times `eventListner` is added in your life cycle.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

Chanage your Listner ChildEventListener to ValueEventListener.

```
 cartRef = mCustDB.child(Email).child("mycart");
    cartRef.addChildEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Timber.d("onChildChanged > " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to know about the changed only not the whole Value. So i'm using ChildEventListener!